# Deleting entity in a relationship with JPA and kotlin gives SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException

Tags: kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I am writing a Spring Boot app in Kotlin where I have a couple of JPA entities, User and Community, and a many to many relationship that I modeled as a separate Participation entity since I needed to add some fields to the relatioship.

The behavior that I want to achieve is that when I delete a user or a community, all the participations involving the deleted entity must be deleted, so I set `CascadeType.ALL` like this:

```kotlin
// User.kt
@Entity
class User(
    @Id
    var id: String,
    var username: String,
    var email: String,
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "participant", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    var participations: MutableSet<Participation> = mutableSetOf()
)
```

```kotlin
// Community.kt
@Entity
class Community(
    var name: String,
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "community", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    var participations: MutableSet<Participation> = mutableSetOf(),
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    var id: Long? = null,
)
```

```kotlin
// Participation.kt
@Entity
class Participation(
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    var participant: User,
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "community_id")
    var community: Community,
    var role: CommunityRole = CommunityRole.USER,
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    var id: Long? = null
)
```

But when I do `communityRepository.deleteById(communityId)` I get:

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydatabase`.`participation`, CONSTRAINT `FKcfl4kwkw9gk83wf3i26uvhyb` FOREIGN KEY (`community_id`) REFERENCES `community` (`id`))
```

Comment: I think you also need to set `orphanRemoval = true` in the `OneToMany` annotation.

Comment: I tried this but I end up with the exact same behavior